# Where should I store user uploaded pics and files

Tags: django, django-storage

I am working on a django app to store user pics and photos. 
What is the optimal approach to store individual user media.
File Sizes are no more than 5MB.
The data is persistent.

The approach i have in mind is:

1. On form data submission, Upload it to an FTP server using django-storages.
2. Store the url and fetch it via http later for user.

[How to save upload files to another server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369441/how-to-save-upload-files-to-another-server)

I have seen the answers and I don't know what type of queue needs to be used.

Answer (score 0):

you'd usually save the file locally and then latter upload it to some cloud service asynchronously, preferably using something like [django-celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/)

see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/671255/41576)