# Upload File With Django Via FTP

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

A quick question has anyone wrote a script or is there package that allows for model uploads to a separate server to store files. I do not want to use Amazon S3 since this application is for a non-profit who has limited funds. I have a server available to store files.

I am looking for any suggestions and tips.

Comment: Are you asking if you can use django with your database living on a different server? Or are you asking if you can store certain files related to models on another server?

Comment: I have the a postgres database with heroku and a separate server available just store files. So they are two separate entities.

Comment: So you want to store your static files on the other server?

Comment: Well pdf's uploaded by users not css, js

Comment: Here ya go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369441/how-to-save-upload-files-to-another-server

Comment: Thank you nick for your help